# Applying a fixed offset when incrementing a variable a user-provided number of times

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a file that prints the number of proxies that I create using a script I have.

This is what I have but for some reason its not giving me the output I want.

```
echo "How many proxies will you like to create?"
read userInput


for (( portid=10000; portid<=$userInput; portid++ ))
do  
    echo 42.56.35.1:$portid:test:run
done
```

Lets say after I answer the question:

```
How many proxies will you like to create?
```

and I reply

```
5
```

Then I want my output to be:

```
42.56.35.1:100001:test:run
42.56.35.1:100002:test:run
42.56.35.1:100003:test:run
42.56.35.1:100004:test:run
42.56.35.1:100005:test:run
```

I want the numbers to continue from 10000 and so on but depending on how many proxies i tell it to make.

Comment: `portid<=(10000+userInput)`

Comment: or just run `portid` from `0` to `5`, and `echo "42.56.35.1:$((portid+10000)):test:run`

Comment: Typo I meant to say 10001,10002, etc not 100001

Comment: *Shrug*. Principle still holds. Absolutely **nothing** here is specific to bash -- you'd need to change your `for` loop exact same way in any other language with a comparable concept.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're telling the loop to end when `portid` is more than `5` (or whatever value the user entered) -- but you're initializing it at 10000, so unless the user requested a very large range, it's **always** more than 5.

---

One easy approach is to loop starting at 1, and apply the offset inside the loop:

```
for (( portid=1; portid<=userInput; portid++ ))
do  
    echo "42.56.35.1:$(( portid + 10000 )):test:run"
done
```

Another is to apply the increment on both ends:

```
for (( portid=10001; portid<=(userInput + 10000); portid++ ))
do  
    echo "42.56.35.1:$portid:test:run"
done
```